# Downloaded mp4 file wont play under any video player

Tags: video, download, mp4, hls

I downloaded a video using Youtube-dlg its was a HLS stream and it downloaded fully except Youtube-dlg told me there was an error when it finished..
I presume that the site i downloaded from made it this way so to discourage downloading..
anyway I have a 200 mb file sitting in my pc waiting to get fixed .. has anyone happen to have any experience with this ??

Comment: Can you download again with youtube-dl using console and post a screenshot of the output or share the video URL? Because using another player would just be a workaround, not a solution imho.

Comment: unfortunately, im a little busy and I decided to just delete the file and not download from that website again.. I also tried video repair programs before deleting it but they did nothing.. The website is `yesmovies` (.ag).. and I believe any show u try to download  would have the same result.. you get the m3u8 link from Devtools>network then paste it in youtube-dlg

Comment: @hosa why have you not accepted **any** of your answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I have experienced this many a times. Sometimes, when we download a mp4 file, it may result in errors due to several reasons including interruption while downloading the MP4 videos, improper system termination while editing . mp4 file, transfer error, network inconsistency etc. etc.

But, we still get a large chunk of the file and seems like it'll eventually find its place in recycle bin without even giving us a chance to watch a single bit. So, is there a way to play the incompletely downloaded file in any way? I think there is one. Since, tons of video players are available online, and assuming that you didn't try all of them, I think you left out VLC player.

VLC player is a great tool with ability to decode different types of corrupted media files. Just open the VLC player and drag the incompletely downloaded media into the VLC Player. In almost all the cases, this should do the trick. I have tried this while playing several incompletely downloaded media from YouTube. This should work for you too.

Comment: Also.. SMPlayer (based on linux mplayer).. sometimes.. I can get an open in vlc.. sometimes.. SMPlayer with a corrupted file.  Most of it depends on a complete header.